# Arch Linux thinks I have about 16 gigs of ram when I only have 8

Tags: linux, swap, ram

I have done several searches and I cannot find anything on Google about why but arch has allocated 7.7 gigs to ram and 7.9 to swap.

- I only have 8 gigs ram.
- it allocated more ram to swap than regular

How could I change the allocations?

output of `cat /proc/meminfo`:

`MemTotal:        8091960 kB
MemFree:         4925736 kB
MemAvailable:    6131188 kB
Buffers:          268936 kB
Cached:          1219460 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1527516 kB
Inactive:        1301140 kB
Active(anon):     768904 kB
Inactive(anon):   711440 kB
Active(file):     758612 kB
Inactive(file):   589700 kB
Unevictable:          32 kB
Mlocked:              32 kB
SwapTotal:       8300540 kB
SwapFree:        8300540 kB
Dirty:              1960 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1306968 kB
Mapped:           382800 kB
Shmem:            140100 kB
Slab:             197964 kB
SReclaimable:     163104 kB
SUnreclaim:        34860 kB
KernelStack:        6864 kB
PageTables:        29200 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    12346520 kB
Committed_AS:    3927808 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    186368 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      584316 kB
DirectMap2M:     7716864 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB`

Comment: [swap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/swap) is, by definition, not using RAM.

Comment: The same (or a little bit more) swap then you got RAM is a good start...  Also remember that swap-space may be used if you hibernate (put RAM to disk).  In the old days, one said twice as much swap as RAM - but for Linux, that "rule" only applied when you had 512MB or less (or was it 256MB).  There were however Unix-systems (at least one) where the design was such that you always *had to* have at least twice the amount of swap.  Early Linux had limits on how much swap per partition, number of swap-partitions and/or total swap. TBC

Comment: Continued...  To really decide how much swap you need, you really should carefully audit how much memory the processes you (and your users) run actually need - but remember that swap is no substitute for too little RAM.  That said - and this from somebody who only got 2GB (not "only" 8GB like you) RAM - most systems will be able to keep *all* processes in RAM.  However they don't *need* to, so swap is used to store "unused" memory-pages of processes - and sometimes whole "unused" processes - thus freeing up RAM... this "unused" RAM, is then used as buffer and cache, to speed up things.

Comment: The 7.7GB number probably comes from ~300MB of physical RAM having been permanently allocated to the kernel.  That RAM still exists but can't be used for ordinary programs.

Comment: What leads you to believe "Arch thinks you have 16GB RAM"?

Comment: @zwol Do you have a reputable source for that? And that it's not simply the results of the **Giga**byte vs [**Gibi**byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) mess, i.e. the same reason HDDs almost never seem to have as much space as advertised, and the larger the HDD the more space is missing?

Comment: @8bittree The numbers don't work out right for that. 8e9 / (1024*1024*1024) is 7.4505, not 7.7. It can't be the other way around, either; if the system information screen were displaying RAM capacity in decimal gigabytes, it would say 8.59. Also, as far as I know, RAM cards have never been subject to the decimal/binary multiplier mess; their advertised sizes have always used binary multipliers, even if they're not using the "ibi" prefixes. This is because RAM intrinsically comes in power-of-2 sizes whereas disk drives can be manufactured to any multiple of the block size.

Comment: HNQ creates another perplexingly highly voted question that proceeds from a false premise without even explaining why that premise was assumed.

Comment: @zwol 8000MB comes out to 7629MiB, but a ceiling rounding strategy seems odd, not too mention 8000MB doesn't look right. But I did find this: [`MemTotal: Total usable ram (i.e. physical ram minus a few reserved bits and the kernel binary code)`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt), which lends at least some support to your claim.

Comment: (http://i.imgur.com/toFhVrr.png) Here is a screenshot i took of a system monitor

Comment: @jaw2233 If you could run the command `cat /proc/meminfo` in a Terminal window, on the computer you're asking about, and edit the output into your question, that would clarify matters.

Comment: @zwol ok its done

Comment: @jaw2233 Nowhere in your screenshot does it say "16GB", so how did you come to conclude that Arch thinks you have 16GB?

Comment: I concluded that because i assumed that swap meant a portion of ram reserved for os but the other comments showed that isnt the case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What this is telling you is that you have 16GB of *virtual memory*.

Virtual memory is the total of physical RAM and swap space added up.

It's a way of letting your system run more programs than it physically has the space for.

How much swap should be allocated to a machine is a complicated and opinionated question; ask 2 people and get 3 answers :-)

Your setup isn't bad, and I wouldn't recommend making changes to it until you learn a lot more about how virtual memory works and how to tune it.  It's a good starting point.

Comment: "*Virtual memory is the total of physical RAM and swap space added up.*" No, it's not. For example, on a 64-bit machine with 4GB of RAM and 4 GB of swap, I can memory map a 64GB file. That's 64GB of virtual memory, even though RAM and swap add up to 8GB.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz is correct. It's more proper to say that virtual memory is *what can be addressed as memory,* preferably with *something* backing it. That something can be either RAM chips, some I/O port, a swap partition, a swap file on disk, or a regular file with no special meaning to the operating system or memory manager. It's also not required to function in such a way that if you write something and then immediately read it back, you read back what you wrote. (For instance some I/O registers function in this way.)

Comment: It's the "Unix 101 beginners version".  I also didn't mention how executable pages can be added as read-only pages to the memory map and other fun things like overallocation.  As a first level approximation, however, VM=RAM+swap is close enough, and is all this question was really about.

Comment: _"What this is telling you is that you have 16GB of virtual memory."_ - There's no way to know that since the OP has never explained *why* he thinks Arch says he has 16GB.

Comment: @StephenHarris It's first level approximations that cause the misunderstanding behind this question. Simplifications are fine, so long as they either indicate that they are simplifications or are factually correct.